# How can I make VS Code move the cursor after the CSS semicolon after I accept a suggestion?

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier

I am wondering, is there a way in CSS that when I press tab after suggestion, cursor goes behind semi-colon?

Right now when I tab on suggestion I get the cursor before semi-colon and I have to move the arrow just to go to next property.

Comment: by "behind", do you mean "after"?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Ctrl + Enter` to create & jump to a new line without breaking the current line. Thus the semicolon remains where it belongs.

`Ctrl + Shift + Enter` if you are using IntelliJ Keybindings.